# ffmpeg wont work if filename has spaces

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

So I did `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "list.txt" -c copy Final/done.mp4`

and the inside of list.txt is:

```
file "News/The Verge/Test1/Video/output0.mp4"
file "News/The Verge/Test2/Video/output1.mp4"
file "News/The Verge/Test3/Video/output2.mp4"
file "News/The Verge/Test4/Video/output3.mp4"
file "News/The Verge/Test5/Video/output4.mp4"
```

But it returns:

```
[concat @ 00000142d4bce7c0] Impossible to open '"News/The'
list.txt: Invalid argument
```

How would I fix it this?

I tried `file "News/"The Verge"/Test1/Video/output0.mp4"`, but that didn't work for some reason even though that's what I do with the cd command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Syntax):

> `file path`
> Path to a file to read; special characters and spaces must be escaped with backslash or single quotes.

You used double-quotes. Not only they don't help in escaping spaces; the error you got suggests a double-quote is treated as a part of the filename. In your situation the simplest approach is to replace double-quotes with single-quotes. You can fix the file with `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/\"/'/g" list.txt
```

Comment: The problem is unlikely to go away with this. It appears as ffmpeg has a problem with parsing arguments that contain space characters. Quoting isn't considered in the argument parser. Swapping to another type of quote is unlikely to change anything IF I'm guessing right.

Comment: @Hannu `Quoting isn't considered in the argument parser.`  -- The troublesome quotes are not parsed by a shell. They are in a *file* that `ffmpeg` parses *on its own* and the parser it uses behaves as documented. I have recreated the problem and solved it by applying the exact `sed` command I posted. The answer stands.

Comment: I tried ```ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 sed -i "s/\"/'/g" list.txt -c copy Final/done.mp4``` and it just gave me ```s/"/'/g: No such file or directory```

Comment: @MrPigbot The command I gave you is standalone. It will change every `"` to `'` in `list.txt`.